# Table pagination trouble on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm facing some trouble at pagination on laravel. Already paginate the table. But in view page the numbers are not okay.This is how it's look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/407Oo.png

The other problem is when I press the numbers, links are dead and giving me this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

**This my route:**

```
Route::get("/", "PagesController@welcome");

Route::post("/search", "PagesController@search")->name('search.route');
```

**And this my view:**

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $q = $request->q;
        if ($q !== null && trim($q) !== ""){//here

            $estates = \DB::table('allestates')
                ->where("building_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("company_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("region","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orderBy('price')->paginate(10);


            if(count($estates) > 0){
                return view("search", compact('estates'))->withQuery($q);
            }

        }

        $estates = array();//here
        return view("search", compact('estates'))->withMessage("No Found!");//here
    }
```

The other thing is in controller I can't add `->paginate(10)` with `->get()`  it's returning as a error like:

> Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::paginate does not exist.

I really appreciate any help to solve this problems. Thank you!
By the way if connected or not I don't know, but I already deleted/changed "boostrap" file in public.

Comment: You can make a new LengthAwarePaginator. General usage like this: 
$new_paginate = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentItems, count($items), $perPage, $currentPage);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problems.

Changed the controller right below.

```
$q = $request->q;
$estates = \DB::table('allestates')
                ->where("building_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("company_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("region","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orderBy('price')->paginate(10);

return view("search", compact('estates','q'));
```

Changed the view

```
@if(count($estates))
    @foreach($estates as $estate)
        <!-- ... -->
    @endforeach
    {{ $estates ->appends(['q' => $q])->links() }}
@else
    <div class="alert">
        Not found!
    </div>
@endif
```

I also changed the route right below.

```
Route::any("/search", "PagesController@search")->name('search.route');
```

Also added css for pagination buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `paginate()` method to `DB` facade. Because `DB` return collection instance. But `paginate()` is the method of Model. You need to manually create a paginator from a collection instance. Try this:

```
$estates = \DB::table('allestates')
                ->where("building_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("address","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("company_name","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("region","LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orderBy('price')->get();

$showPerPage = 10;

$perPagedData = $estates
            ->slice((request()->get('page') - 1) * $showPerPage, $showPerPage)
            ->all();

        $estates = new Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($perPagedData, count($estates), $showPerPage, request()->get('page'));
```

Source: [Manually Creating A Paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator)

Comment: this is what i am getting: `Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator' not found`

Comment: okay, I fix the that error with adding back \ but, now no data showing just a blank page mate!

Comment: @KubilayTurgut Go to the source link. Read & Do. I can not help you in every step.